# Spring does not add namespace for type String in SOAP message

Tags: java, spring, namespaces, jaxb, jaxb2

I have generated by Java objects using JAXB2.2. I am using Spring 3.0.1, Java 1.6, and JBoss AS 5.

My problem is that when my application sends generates and sends a SOAP message, I have an element that is of type anyType, generated as an Object in Java. The sent request message will be formed like this:

```
<field xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

But the schema expects this:

```
<field xsi:type="xs:string" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

As you can see, the missing namespace definition is this:

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

The generated java output for this element is:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "MetadataElement", namespace = "http://...", propOrder = {
"field"
})
public class MetadataElement {

@XmlElement(required = true)
protected Object field;
```

Any ideas on how I can generate the missing namespace?

Comment: What is the code that has been generate in the Java class for that anyType element? Please indicate the field type and name and all annotations and the part of the class comment referring to this property.

Comment: And the namespace prefix definition does not occur at some parent element either?

Comment: added the generated java class. And no, the namespace and/or prefix does not occur at any other element.

Comment: Works for me: Java code containing an @XmlElement like field in MetadataElement marshals correctly, with xmlns:xs=... being included. However, I don't see how `field` with the annotations as shown, should produce an XML element with the tag `<value ...>`.

Comment: Corrected wrong reference. Hmm, I wonder why all other namespace definitions are generated correctly for me, but this one particular is not...